# How do I downgrade my BeautifulSoup version in EC2 linux environmet?

Tags: python, linux, beautifulsoup

I used to run a crawler that parses a website with bs4(version: 4.3.2),
but I have a parsing error when this comes to my linux.
And I think this is because of my bs4 version because the current version is higher(4.5.3).

So I decided to remove my current bs4(4.5.3), and replace with my old one(4.3.2).
I removed using pip uninstall bs4, but whenever I import bs4 in my python console, it is still alive... what's wrong?

> > > import bs4
> > >       bs4
> > >       
> > >       print bs4.**version**
> > >       4.5.3

Above is what happens "even" after I removed it.
(So it is actually "NOT" removed properly.)

I downloaded bs4 old version (4.3.2) and I don't have any idea
how I can 1)remove the current version, 2)setup the old one, and finally 3)replace the directory path so that my python will point out the old one, not the current.

What should I suppose to do? Please Help!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 pip uninstall bs4   # Python2
 pip3 uninstall bs4  # Python3


 python2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2 
 python2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7 
 python3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3 
 python3.4 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.4
```

Comment: I didn't meant for this.
I wanted to know how I can "replace" with the old version, not just installing.

Comment: dont replace,delete all,after this reinstall

Comment: thanks. as you said, I removed every bs4-relevant things, and then reinstalled the old one which was desired. good!

Comment: I'm glad for you)